# fstab entry for external nextcloud drive is not working

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, fstab, nextcloud

I'm pretty desperate right now... I just want my external hard drive to automount when I reboot my raspberry pi, but the fstab entry is not working and I don't know why. Here is my fstab:

```
PARTUUID=afdf92d1-01  /boot           vfat    defaults,flush    0       2
PARTUUID=afdf92d1-02  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
UUID=ba045e16-632e-4b55-babf-da2cf167d690  /media/myCloudDrive  btrfs  defaults,nofail,x-systemd.device-timeout=9  0  0
```

I edited it several times, but nothing solved it. I hope you can help me!

System Information:

```
NextCloudPi version  v1.49.0
OS                   Debian GNU/Linux 11. 5.15.32-v8+ (aarch64)
automount            yes
USB devices          sda 
datadir              /media/myCloudDrive/ncdata
data in SD           no
data filesystem      btrfs
data disk usage      961G/1.9T
rootfs usage         9.2G/59G
swapfile             /var/swap
dbdir                /var/lib/mysql
Nextcloud check      ok
Nextcloud version    24.0.3.2
HTTPD service        up
PHP service          up
MariaDB service      up
Redis service        up
HPB service          down
Postfix service      up
Internet check       ok
public IPv4          xxx
public IPv6          xxx
Port check 80        open (ipv4)
Port check 443       open (ipv4)
IP                   192.xxx.x.x
Gateway              192.xxx.x.x
Interface            eth0
certificates         none
NAT loopback         no
Uptime               13:31
```

## Solution

**The automount feature of nextcloudpi was configured to be active, it seems that it's not working together with the fstab entry. After deactivating the automount-feature and rebooting, the usb-drive was automatically mounted like it should.**

Comment: Do we talk about NAS or attached USB drive? Because Nextcloud is NAS software.

Comment: It's an attached USB drive which I want to automount when I reboot the raspberry pi. I don't think it's relevant here which type of software Nextcloud is in this case, or is it?

Comment: It is. Do Nextcloud expose directly the disks or LUN? Or it create Samba/NFS share?

Comment: I use nextcloudpi, I edited the system informations in my original post. Does it help you to solve the problem?

Comment: Ok I solved it on my own, this is how:
The automount feature of nextcloudpi was configured to be active, it seems that it's not working together with the fstab entry. After deactivating the automount-feature and rebooting, the usb-drive was automatically mounted like it should. 
Thank you for your support!